# React.js NavBar: Is it possible to reference a different component's markup? (Trying to create a navbar that references to components in one route)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Basically I'm trying to make a navbar for a personal website application in which the navbar references content (About/Skills, etc.) all on single page (route). When making the navbar, I can easily reference markup with ids/classes BUT I would have to put all the html in one file.

I noticed that if I were to separate each content into its own react file (About.jsx, Skills.jsx, etc.) and import them, there didn't seem to be a way for me to reference the react component's markup.

I also noticed with react router, this wasn't feasible because each component would be on a separate route (which I don't want) rather than on a single route.

---

This is my current navbar file below; How exactly Can I import and reference the markup of the separate components?

```
import React from 'react';
import "../Styles/NavBar.scss";
import About from "./About.jsx"; (Not used)
import Skills from "./Skills.jsx"; (Not Used)
import Projects from "./Projects.jsx"; (Not used)

const NavBar = () => (
    <div class="MainDivWrapper">
        <div class="NavBarDiv">
            <h1 class="NavBarH1">NavBar</h1>
            <br/>
            <nav> 
                <a href="#AboutDiv">About</a>
                <a href="#SkillsDiv">Skills</a>
                <a href="#ProjectsDiv">Projects</a>
            </nav>
            {/* <div id="AboutDiv">
                <h1>About Me</h1>
                <span>Just some text</span>
            </div>
            <div id="SkillsDiv">
                <h1>Skills</h1>
                <span>Just some text</span>
            </div>
            <div id="ProjectssDiv">
                <h1>Projects</h1>
                <span>Just some text</span>
            </div> */}

        </div>
        <hr class="HeaderDivider"/>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Your first order of business is understanding the difference between JSX and HTML. I will kindly recommended you revisit how to use React Router afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reference a JSX import like that:

```
/* Component have to start with a capital letter. file name can be anything (usually is the same as component) */
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent"

export default function MyApp() {
  return (
    <div>
      /* other html/components here */

      <MyComponent /> // selfing close tag
      /* or */
      <MyComponent> // with `children`
        some content
      </MyComponent>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is a codesandbox implementation of your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-reactjs-navbar-is-it-possible-to-reference-a-different-components-markup-64oic?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you so much :)!!! This sandbox imp. was really helpful. Also, I could have sworn I did this, but I probably messed up somewhere >.>.